# Unable to the "import turtle" in python3.5.2

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The error I get is:
`No module named '_tkinter'`

I have tried using:
`sudo apt-get install python python-tk idle python-pmw python-imaging`

The turtle works in python2.7.1

Comment: Try `apt-get install python3-tk python3-imaging`

Answer (score 0):

You probably only installed the turtle for python 2.7.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

(and others you may need)